# Easy way to create Zen-Coding Snippets in Sublime Text 2

Tags: emmet, sublimetext2

Like in Eclipse or Aptana, **you have a interface for create snippets and shortcuts for them**.
But, in Sublime Text 2, just have a .py file.

Anyone know how I can do that?

*Sorry for my english, I'm Brazilian.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sexy-code-snippet-management-with-gists/

It's about setting up Gists on GitHub and using it as a snippet library through Sublime Text.

There are lots of other tips on Sublime Text on net.tutsplus.com too.

Comment: Thanks, I read the post and try to execute the instructions. Anyway what I really wanted was something like zen-coding, for just one reason: snippet * 4. The snippets of Sublime Text 2, to my knowledge, do not accept external parameters, such as a [href = # = class test] {hello world}.